# JavaCV - Rendering to a GL Surface

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

Using JavaCV to consume a multicast stream, I want to render the video frames in a GLSurfaceView. The frames are grabbed using the FFmpegFrameGrabber class; I have successfully output the captured frames to sdcard and a non-GL surface for visual debuggging. I have looked all over for a solution or clue to no avail; here is the section of code where help is needed:

 `// get the frame
 opencv_core.IplImage img = capture.grab();
 if (img != null) {
   opencv_core.CvMat rgbaImg = opencv_core.CvMat.create(height, width, CV_8U, 4);
   Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   // convert colorspace
   cvCvtColor(img, rgbaImg, CV_BGR2RGBA);
   bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(rgbaImg.getByteBuffer());
   Rect rect = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
   Canvas c = surface.lockCanvas(rect);
   c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
   surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
   if (bitmap != null) {
     bitmap.recycle();
   }
   if (rgbaImg != null) {
     rgbaImg.release();
   }
 }`

Also if there is a more optimal way to do anything above, let me know.

**Edit** Since there's not much action on the first part of this question, would a "workaround" of rendering on the SufaceTexture that is used to create the Surface be a possibility instead?

  `SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(textureId);
  surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
  surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);`

**Note:** I am forced to stick with Android 4.2.2 for now.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to display videos that needs to sync with the audio portion?

Comment: Theres no requirement for audio here, nor any syncing to anything. Everything is in GL so that widgets etc can be overlaid or displayed on the same screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg with wild video formats:

For your first method, you can speed it up by a shared bitmap and the other resources, that will eliminate any memory allocation and speed it up a lot.

As for rendering FFmpeg results to a GLSurfaceView, you should look here:

(I have used both JJmpeg and JavaCV)

https://code.google.com/p/jjmpeg/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fffmpeg-0.10-android%2Fjjmpeg%2Fsrc%2Fau%2Fnotzed%2Fjjmpeg%2Fmediaplayer

Most of the gems are here: (GLESVideoRenderer.onDrawFrame method) 
https://code.google.com/p/jjmpeg/source/browse/branches/ffmpeg-0.10-android/jjmpeg/src/au/notzed/jjmpeg/mediaplayer/GLESVideoRenderer.java

Basic idea is to load the frames into 2D texture array, and then draw it.

You can modify the FFmpegFrameGrabber to a renderer for the GLSurfaceView, framerates will vary between devices.

If you know the video format:

What you really should do since you are already on Android 4.2.2, is to use MediaCodec from SDK and push the frames directly onto a surface.